# Issue with Texture Mapping in Python Ray Tracer

Tags: python

I'm currently working on a ray tracer in Python, and I'm trying to implement texture mapping for spheres. I've created a TexturedSphere class that extends the basic Sphere class, and I'm using texture coordinates to sample colors from a texture image. However, I'm encountering a TypeError that I'm having trouble resolving.

Here's the relevant portion of my code:

```
class TexturedSphere(Sphere):
    def __init__(self, center, r, texture_path, mirror=0.5):
        super().__init__(center, r, vec3(1, 1, 1), mirror)
        self.texture = np.array(Image.open(texture_path)) / 255.0

    def diffusecolor(self, M):
        u = 0.5 + np.arctan2(M.z - self.c.z, M.x - self.c.x) / (2 * np.pi)
        v = 0.5 - np.arcsin((M.y - self.c.y) / self.r) / np.pi
        u_pixel = int(u * (self.texture.shape[1] - 1))
        v_pixel = int(v * (self.texture.shape[0] - 1))
        return vec3(*self.texture[v_pixel, u_pixel])
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```